# How to use an array in a condition for Azure DevOps YAML

Tags: azure, yaml, devops

I have a template that defines an array of branches for each environment, so that I can control which branches cause a deploy to a particular environment. For example, the only branch I want deployed to production is master, but for UAT I want release, hotfix, and master. I've set-up a parent template that calls downstream templates in an 'each' loop. Inside the deploy template, I want to compare the array of allowed branches against the current branch to determine whether to proceed or not. Here's part of the parent template that passes the branches arrays:

```
- template: pipeline-templates/environment-pipeline.yml
  parameters:
    envs: 
      - name: devtest
        branches: 
        - 'refs/heads/master'
        - 'refs/heads/develop'
        - 'refs/heads/hotfix/'
        - 'refs/heads/release/'
      - name: nightly
        branches: 
        - 'refs/heads/master'
        - 'refs/heads/develop'
        - 'refs/heads/hotfix/'
        - 'refs/heads/release/'
      - name: qa
        branches: 
        - 'refs/heads/master'
        - 'refs/heads/hotfix/'
        - 'refs/heads/release/'
      - name: prod
        branches: 
        - 'refs/heads/master'
```

The `environment-pipeline.yml` below then calls the deploy template for each environment.

```
parameters:
  - name: envs # collection of environments to create/deploy
    type: object
    default:
      env:
        name: ''
        branches: []

stages:
- ${{ each env in parameters.envs }}:
  - template: deploy.yml
    parameters:
      environmentName: ${{ env.name }}
      onlyForBranches: ${{ env.branches }}
```

The above all works fine (note, I've deleted a lot of the YAML to simplify the example). The next stage is to use a condition with the array of branches in the deploy template. This is how I was hoping it would work, but doesn't.

```
parameters:
  environmentName: ''
  onlyForBranches: []

stages:
  - stage: branch_gate
    condition: and(succeeded(), in(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], ${{ parameters.onlyForBranches }}))

# then the deploy stages go here if above condition passes
```

This results in the following error:

> Unable to convert from Array to String.

Is there some way to make this work, or should I use a different approach?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`in` is not the function to use. It takes n arguments and is true if the first argument equals any of the rest: `in('B', 'A', 'B', 'C') => true`

Try [containsvalue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#containsvalue) instead:

`condition: and(succeeded(), containsvalue(${{ parameters.onlyForBranches }}, variables['Build.SourceBranch']))`

Comment: This doesn't work when 'onlyForBranches' parameter is an array. How to convert array into multiple strings?

Comment: containsvalue works specifically for arrays.

"Evaluates True if the left parameter is an array, and any item equals the right parameter. Also evaluates True if the left parameter is an object, and the value of any property equals the right parameter."

Comment: From what I can tell the Build.SourceBranch variable will not match the folders defined in OnlyForBranches. /refs/heads/hotfix will not evaluate to true if the source branch is refs/heads/hotfix/hotfix_1.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with schummar on the use of [containsValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#containsvalue), however the suggested approach did not work for me either.

Instead try this:

`condition: and(succeeded(), ${{ containsValue(parameters.onlyForBranches, variables['Build.SourceBranch']) }})`

Comment: This worked for me too. I can use it with for each as well:  stages: \n - ${{ each env in parameters.Environments }}: \n   - stage: ${{ env }}. \n    condition: ${{ containsValue(parameters.DeployTo, env) }}